# What does this tattoo say and where can I find the symbols online? (Characters identified: 寵命力)

Tags: meaning, character-identification

I saw this tattoo and I really want to know what it says. I'm not sure if it's Chinese or Japanese. What does it say and where can I find the symbols online?

[image]

Comment: The second character is "命" but I'm not sure what the others are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three characters from the picture look like "寵", "命" and "力“. The followings are the common usage of the words.

寵：(verb) Love, favor, spoil, dote; (noun) things or person that is loved/favored (eg. 新寵，寵物)

命：(verb) command, admonish, appoint (eg.命令); (noun) life, lifespan, fate (eg.命運)

力：(noun) Strength, ability, power; (adv) doing something with the best effort (eg.力爭上游）

The term "寵命力" does not look like anything meaningful to me.

Comment: A lot of non-Chinese speakers having tattoo don't care if it make a meaningful phrase. They just pick English words they want and replace them with Chinese characters in a tattoo. In this case, the  tattoo owner  might want it to express " cherish (寵) life (命) strength (力). If he could understand Chinese and wanted to make a meaningful phrase, he would have made it " 珍惜 生命 力量" ( cherish the strength of life)

Comment: Thanks for the respond i really appreicate it, so is the tattoo in chinese letter or japanese because i try looking online and cant find them , is there somewhere i can look up the letter or meanings thank you